# Add column to all tables through migration in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, migration, database-migration

As our project scaled we decided that every single data should belong to companies that created them. Therefore I'm to add a column "data_owner_company_id" that points to the company that owns given record. Yes it's possible to generate migration to add this column to each model but that is not really feasible since there is **120+ tables & models.** How can i tackle this with minimum effort ?

For the model part i figured i can easily apply it to all models by inheritance, but not sure about migration.

TL;DR
How to add int column to all tables by migration ?

Database: MySQL v8
Framework: Laravel 8, PHP 7.3

Comment: I supose you have to do it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple if you find all the tables' names in your database, you have to loop and create columns for each and every table.

Try creating columns using queues as it will be a heavy job for 120 tables.

Check the following code:

```
class CreateDataOwnerCompanyIdtoEachTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up ()
    {
        $columns = 'Tables_in_' . env('DB_DATABASE');//This is just to read the object by its key, DB_DATABASE is database name.
        $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');

        foreach ( $tables as $table ) {
            //todo add it to laravel jobs, process it will queue as it will take time.
            Schema::table($table->$columns, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->unsignedInteger('data_owner_company_id');
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down ()
    {
        $columns = 'Tables_in_' . env('DB_DATABASE');//This is just to read the object by its key, DB_DATABASE is database name.
        $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');

        foreach ( $tables as $table ) {
            //todo add it to laravel jobs, process it will queue as it will take time.
            Schema::table($table->$columns, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('data_owner_company_id');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like it'll do the trick. I'll try to implement it. But i didn't understand one thing, what do we need table columns for ? Isn't (array of) table names enough for schema ?

Comment: That's actually a typo, that is not a table column that is individual table names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that it's going to work, but here it goes:

Create class that extends `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;`

In constructor call parent construntor and then

```
$this->unsignedBigInteger('data_owner_company_id')->nullable();
```

Use your new class in migrations instead of default `Blueprint`

Comment: Interesting approach. Are there any downsides in handling it this way rather that with a programmatic migration?